# symfony2 custom input name

Tags: rest, symfony, symfony-2.3

I'm building a REST API using Symfony 2.3 & FOSRestBundle.

Do anyone know how to **customize POST parameter keys**, so that, for instance:
***"company_mybundle_user[firstName]={value}"*** becomes

***"firstName={value}"***.

The latter wouldn't work because of the form validation inside "postUsersAction(Request $request)":

```
// src/Company/MyBundle/Controller/UserController.php
// ...
public function postUsersAction(Request $request)
{   
    $entity = new User();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request); 

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);          
        $em->flush();
        $view = new View($entity);      
    } else {
        $view = View::create($form);    
    }
    return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
}
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

Empty the value returned by "UserType::getName()" will remove the prefixes of parameters.
Hence "**company_mybundle_user[lastName]**" becomes **lastName**

Before:

```
// src/Company/MyBundle/Form/UserType.php
// ...
public function getName()
{
    return 'company_mybundle_user';
}
```

After:

```
// src/Company/MyBundle/Form/UserType.php
// ...
public function getName()
{
    return '';
}
```

PS: make sure to clear cache before testing:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Comment: If you have a better solution, please share :)

Comment: As far as I know you can leave the form name as `company_mybundle_user` and submit the request data using `$form->submit($request->get($form->getName()))` rather than `$form->handleRequest()` (which kind of does the same, but with a bit more involvement.. $_FILES and what not... I think).

Comment: FYI: Remember, if you delete a name you will not be able to style each block separately in Twig and extend forms by getting Parent!

Comment: @PawełKolanowski Indeed.. But this is a REST API, so there's no need to build a form, right?

Comment: @SebastienGillet I know, so I wrote it just for information ;)